How to read encoded Constructor Arguments
some contract has the following constructor:
constructor (address _walletsForCharity, uint160[] memory _pair)

Now I want to check which _walletsForCharity were getting used.
When I am on the contract page on etherscan at the "Constructor Arguments" section I can see encoded Constructor Arguments but they are not real wallets.
How can I transform them into wallet addresses?
Thank you!

This post might be helpful.
